# ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 1 - Problem compiling StructureMap Controller Factory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, structuremap

I have a project for which I use StructureMap for dependency injection.  The project compiles fine as a MVC project but after moving everything to a MVC2 project I am now receiving the following error:

> Test.Web.Controllers.StructureMapControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(System.Type)':
>   no suitable method found to
>   override  C:\Test\Web\Controllers\StructureMapControllerFactory.cs    11  40  Test.Web

Here is my StructureMapControllerFactory:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using StructureMap;

namespace Test.Web.Controllers
{
    public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)**
        {

            IController result = null;
            try
            {
                if (controllerType == null) return base.GetControllerInstance(controllerType);
                result = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as Controller;

            }
            catch (StructureMapException)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave());
                throw;
            }

            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

I have found one post semi-related to this issue but it did not offer any insight as to how to resolve my issue: [MVC 2 preview 1 - methods with parameters in the controller fail to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212087/mvc-2-preview-1-methods-with-parameters-in-the-controller-fail-to-load)

Obviously I must be missing a change from the 1.0-2.0 progression, but I am not sure what changed.  Any help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The signature of this method changed. There is now a first argument of RequestContext:

```
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
    RequestContext requestContext, 
    Type controllerType)
```

You'll also need to change your call to base.GetControllerInstance:

```
if (controllerType == null) 
    return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
```

Comment: Thanks so much Craig.  I wonder why this is not reflected in the VS object browser when exploring the System.Web.MVC [2.0.0.0] namespace.

Comment: Not sure, but you can type ov[spacebar] in the code editor (i.e., start typing "override" where you would normally declare a new method) to get the list of overloadable methods for the current class with their signatures.

Answer (score 8):

Craig Stuntz is very correct here.

Just make sure you don't forget to reference System.Web.Routing in addition if your DI is in a different project than you MVC app.

For some reason there were no errors showing in the IDE for me but on compile I would still get a GetControllerInstance "no suitable method found to override."

Once I corrected the missing referenced assembly of System.Web.Routing, all was well...

Comment: Thanks!. I don't know why yet, but adding a reference to System.Web.Routing fixed this for me!

Comment: Thanks for the System.Web.Routing comment - saved me time debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I traced it with the Reflector, and indeed the function signature is changed.
the

**protected internal virtual IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)**

the MVC 2 dll resides here:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 2\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll

Thanks, it solved my issue!